# Beginner's XSLT question: Select node based on a value elsewhere in the XML structure

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

--edited for clarity (hopefully)

I have an XML file that looks something like this:

```
<questionBlock>
    <responses>
      . . .
      <response>
        <degree>1</degree>
        <instdegree>1</instdegree>
      </response>
      . . .
   </responses>
   <question>
      <variable>degree</variable>
      <text>Please select a degree or credential you have pursued.</text>
      <responses>
        <response>
          <label>High School Diploma</label>
          <value>1</value>
        </response>
        <response>
          <label>Certificate</label>
          <value>2</value>
        </response>
      </responses>
      . . .
   </question>
</questionBlock>
```

A subset of the XSLT looks like this:
 `. . .
<xsl:for-each select="responses/response">
   <xsl:variable name="paddedCount" select="concat('00',position())"/>
   <xsl:variable name="s" select="substring($paddedCount,string-length($paddedCount)-1,string-length($paddedCount))"/>
   <xsl:variable name="degree" select="degree" />
. . .` 

In addition to selecting the value of the degree (1), I also want to be able to select the "High School Diploma" based on that value, but I haven't been able to think through the XPath to do this in the general case (e.g., if degree equals 2).

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "select" and "look at"? Do you mean you want to filter by the `label` element, while returning the value from the `degree` element? What is the parent element of `condition` and `responses`?

Comment: Sorry that the question was initially obscure (it made sense in my head as I wrote it). I really need to be able to make the decision based on the value of /question/response, not just the position.

Comment: My solution does noot work for your problem? It is not based on the node position

Comment: I think you should re-clarify again, this is still confusing. You are in a `/questionBlock/responses/response` and want to select `<label>High School Diploma</label>` because that's the one with the same `<value>` as the current `<degree>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xpath: ../../responses[response=current()]/label

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I guess you mean something like this?

```
<xsl:for-each select="responses/response">
  <xsl:variable name="degree" select="degree" />    
  <xsl:variable name="degree-response" select="
    ../question[variable = 'degree']/responses/response[value = $degree]
  " />
  <xsl:value-of select="$degree-response/label" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

Really, you should try to refactor all of this to `<xsl:apply-templates>` instead of `<xsl:for-each>`. The for-each sucks in more ways than one, and it makes things harder than they should be. See: ["Using xsl:for-each is almost always wrong"](http://gregbeech.com/blogs/tech/archive/2006/08/17/using-xsl-for-each-is-almost-always-wrong.aspx)

For-each has it's uses, but all "regular" processing should be done through apply-templates.

---

Original version of the answer (for reference only, since OP has modified the question):

When the context node is `<degree>1</degree>`:

```
parent::condition/following-sibling::responses[1]/response[1]/label
```

or, shorter:

```
../following-sibling::responses[1]/response[1]/label
```

Comment: Thanks, Tomalak. You're quite right, of course, about avoiding for-each. The XSLT was written by a junior programmer (without any experience with functional programming), and I needed to fix it quickly to solve a problem. I really need to go back and refactor the whole thing.